# React.js Problem to sent props and event from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I start learning in React.js now.
But I have some problem to sent props and event from parent to child
In this workshop I want to click "Turn on All" and "Turn Off All" from parent and effect to child
I can do this but in child have problem to set own state to turn on or off
How can I set in child to do that ?

This is my code

App.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Lightbox from "./Lightbox"

function App() {

  const [OnOff, setOnOff] = useState(true)

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row mt-4 mb-4">
        <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
          <button onClick={()=>setOnOff(true)}>Turn On All</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button onClick={()=>setOnOff(false)}>Turn Off All</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <Lightbox status={OnOff} />
        <Lightbox status={OnOff} />
        <Lightbox status={OnOff} />
        <Lightbox status={OnOff} />
        <Lightbox status={OnOff} />        
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Lightbox.js

```
import React,{useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function Lightbox({status}) {

    const [data, setdata] = useState(true)
    const toggleHandler = () => setdata(!data)

    useEffect(() => {
        setdata(status)
    })

    return (
        
        <div className={`card col-md-2 m-2 p-3 ${data?'bg-warning':'bg-dark'}`}>
            {data?<div className="text-center mb-3 text-white">Light On</div>:<div className="text-center mb-3 text-white">Light Off</div>}
            <button onClick={toggleHandler}>{data?"OFF":"ON"}</button>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Lightbox
```

Thank for help

### Screen shot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp5Xb.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcMxL.jpg

Answer (score 1):

you have issues with the useEffect.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Lightbox({ status }) {
  const [data, setdata] = useState(true);

  const toggleHandler = () => {
    setdata((data) => !data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setdata(status);
  }, [status]);

  return (
    <div className={`card col-md-2 m-2 p-3 ${data ? "bg-warning" : "bg-dark"}`}>
      {data ? (
        <div className="text-center mb-3 text-white">Light On</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="text-center mb-3 text-white">Light Off</div>
      )}
      <button onClick={toggleHandler}>{data ? "OFF" : "ON"}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Lightbox;
```

Comment: I change to checking with status but not working on child when call toggleHandler function

Comment: pass status as a dependency in the useEffect()

Comment: Not working on child see in bottom answer

Comment: check the commend below or this edited answer. It works fine now

Answer (score 0):

@Mohammad Faisal

Not working on child

```
import React,{useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function Lightbox({status}) {

    const [data, setdata] = useState(true)
    const toggleHandler = () => setdata(data => !data )

    useEffect(() => {
        setdata(data)
    })

    return (
        
        <div className={`card col-md-2 m-2 p-3 ${status?'bg-warning':'bg-dark'}`}>
            {status?<div className="text-center mb-3 text-white">Light On</div>:<div className="text-center mb-3 text-white">Light Off</div>}
            <button onClick={toggleHandler}>{status?"OFF":"ON"}</button>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Lightbox
```

Comment: and remove  this unnecessary 

useEffect(() => {
        setdata(data)
    })

Comment: Yes I create on thiis
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-display-light-94dbm

Comment: check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/react-display-light-forked-k3eku?file=/src/Lightbox.js

Comment: OK but some wrong , When I turn of some child and click "Turn On All" not working, not working seccond time

Comment: Because when you are changing the status to true in the parent the children's can't detect the change as the previous porp and the current updated prop is same =(true)

You can pass a random number every time the children changes to trigger a re render

Comment: OK I get it please write sample your code thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
{data?"OFF":"ON"}
```

In this part, you return the value but you don't set anything. You can use

```
{data?setData("OFF"): setDate("ON");}
```

to set the values.

Also, you should add the change in props within the "useEffect" hook.

Comment: Not working please edit my code in
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-display-light-94dbm

Comment: I read your code. I still don't know what you do with the data state. It's not used within the code.

Comment: I want to change state to on/off  child like this https://www.uppic.org/image/itg-0031.EX3RB  but I can't do that when useEffect

Comment: The current written code sets and changes the value of the state variable "Data" which should allow you to easily implement your changing the style based on the variable. Add the change in style within the code as the current way it is working, it only loads once during the first render. tl;dr: the current code doesn't re-render the styling again hence why it doesn't work.